# Vue JS axios HTTP500 Internal Server

Tags: vue.js, axios, asp.net-core-webapi

I have create an Asp.Net Core Web API and have checked it is working correctly using postman.
I have downloaded the GitHub Project from this blog: https://paweljw.github.io/2017/09/vue.js-front-end-app-part-3-authentication/
I have modified the url in src/backend/vue-axios/axios.js to my web api url
No matter what I do all I get is:
HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR)OPTIONS - http://localhost:61783/api/token

I have put a break point on the Web API Token method and it is never hit.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Wrong request method? Please show more code =)

Comment: Show the axios code please.

Comment: I think you are trying to make a cross origin request. When you make a cross origin request ex: `GET /token` if your browser detects that the API server  is not the same as the server which served the website, it first makes an `OPTIONS /token` to the API server. So you need to add code in your server to respond correctly to the `OPTIONS` request - after which, if the `OPTIONS` request worked, the browser will make the actual request `GET /token`. More info here: https://enable-cors.org/ and https://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html. There also many SO questions on this: search for "CORS"

Comment: Note: You may not see this issue while using postman because it does not do the CORS check that browsers do so it directly calls `GET /token` without having to call the `OPTIONS /token` which is what is not handled by your server.

Comment: CORS is not the issue as you get a different type of error. Also I have enabled CORS in the Web API project.

Comment: axios.js: import axios from 'axios'

const API_URL = process.env.API_URL || 'http://localhost:61783/api'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
  }
})

Comment: login () {
      this.$http.post('/token', { username: this.email, password: this.password, grant_type: 'password' })
        .then(request => this.loginSuccessful(request))
        .catch(() => this.loginFailed())
    }

Comment: Github project and source code for the front end can be found here: https://github.com/paweljw/bookstore-frontend/releases/tag/part-2 To create a Web API just fire up Visual Studio (I am using 2017) and use the basic template

Comment: What I believe is happening is this: Your server is hitting an error when processing the `OPTIONS` request which happens as a side effect of CORS (and not a direct CORS error). As to why that may be the case really depends on your server code (and is probably not fixable on the frontend VueJS code)

Comment: Also raised the issue here: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2579

Answer (score 0):

Finally cracked it, it was CORS all along!

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders",
                  corsbuilder =>
                  {
                      corsbuilder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                                 .WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080");   
                  });
        });
```

The WithOrigins helped

And enabled cors with a policy on the controller
[EnableCors("AllowAllHeaders")]